# Swift foreach loop within foreach loop within optional child array

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm new to swift, so forgive me if i've got some terminogoly incorrect.

I have a calendar view for a meal planner. The parent array produces the days of a given month, the child array contains the meals planned for that day. There may not be any meals planned for that day, so the child array is optional.

My question is how to properly handle this optional array?

I've tried if statements to check for the array and it throws errors.

JSON for the first few days:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "monthDate": "2024-01-01T00:00:00+0000",
        "recipetitle": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "rtitle": "Garlic Herb Prawn Salad"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "monthDate": "2024-01-02T00:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "monthDate": "2024-01-03T00:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "monthDate": "2024-01-04T00:00:00+0000",
        "recipetitle": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "rtitle": "Garlic Herb Prawn Salad"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have my structs

```
struct MonthDates: Identifiable, Decodable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var monthDate: String
    var recipetitle: [Recipetitle]?
}

struct Recipetitle: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id = Int
    var rtitle: String
}
```

Here is my partial View:

```
ForEach(dataModel.listOfDates, id: \.id) { listItems in
  NavigationLink {
    // Navigate to a new page here
  } label: {
    HStack {
      let sideDate = convertStringToDate(date: listItems.monthDate)
      let abbreviatedDay = abbreviatedDay(date: sideDate)
      let dayNumber = dayNumber(date: sideDate)
      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack {
          VStack {

            Text(abbreviatedDay)
              .font(.caption)
              .foregroundColor(.gray)
            Text(dayNumber)
              .foregroundColor(.red)
          }
          .frame(width: 40)
          Divider()
            .frame(maxHeight: 80)
          VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(listItems.recipetitle, id: \.id) { listItems1 in
              HStack {
                Text(listItems1.rtitle)
                  .font(.system(size: 11))
                Spacer()
                Button {

                } label: {
                  Text("Delete")
                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .controlSize(.regular)
              }
              .padding(.bottom, 3)
              Spacer()
            }
          }
        }
        Divider()
      }
      .frame(height: 100)
      .padding(.leading, 5)
      .padding(.trailing, 5)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the error and which line of code caused it?

Comment: Can't you do `ForEach(listItems.recipetitle ?? [], id: \.id)`?

Comment: Why do you need child array to be optional? Can it not be just an empty, non-optional array?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `if let` just before trying to loop through your `listItems.recipetitle`

```
if let recipeTitle = listItems.recipletitle {
    /// This will get executed if the list item above has one, or more, recipe titles
}
```

Full code below:

```
  ForEach(dataModel.listOfDates, id: \.id) { listItems in
  NavigationLink {
    // Navigate to a new page here
  } label: {
    HStack {
      let sideDate = convertStringToDate(date: listItems.monthDate)
      let abbreviatedDay = abbreviatedDay(date: sideDate)
      let dayNumber = dayNumber(date: sideDate)
      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack {
          VStack {

            Text(abbreviatedDay)
              .font(.caption)
              .foregroundColor(.gray)
            Text(dayNumber)
              .foregroundColor(.red)
          }
          .frame(width: 40)
          Divider()
            .frame(maxHeight: 80)

          if let recipeTitle = listItems.recipleTitle {

             VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(listItems.recipetitle, id: \.id) { listItems1 in
              HStack {
                Text(listItems1.rtitle)
                  .font(.system(size: 11))
                Spacer()
                Button {

                } label: {
                  Text("Delete")
                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .controlSize(.regular)
              }
              .padding(.bottom, 3)
              Spacer()
            }
          }
          }
          
        }
        Divider()
      }
      .frame(height: 100)
      .padding(.leading, 5)
      .padding(.trailing, 5)
    }
  }
}
```

With the code you provided worked for me.